# How to get queries running at specific time

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am using SQL Server 2012. My users claimed that they are facing performance issues last night. I have reviewed all the queries and scripts but not found the exact issue.

Can somebody help me to find out that what was happened at that time? Is there any log/stats in SQL which tell that what queries or scripts was running?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this script can help you find your query.

```
use master 

SELECT execquery.last_execution_time, execsql.text AS [Script], *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql 
--where execquery.last_execution_time between ?? and ??
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

Just put the estimated date and time in the where clause to find your query.

Comment: Thanks for help. This query not help me because it is just giving the information of last execution. If same query run again it will overwrite the previous information. @flicker